# how to send res back to local html file in my directory

Tags: express

this code is coming from local html file in my directory, 
how to send back to html file, res.send("ok")

```
 app.post('/', (req, res) => {
   let data = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    pass: req.body.pass,
    contact: req.body.ccontact
   }
  const action = req.body.action;
  if (action == "submit") {

 req.checkBody("name", "Enter a valid name  address.").notEmpty()
 req.checkBody("email", "Enter a valid email address.").isEmail()
 req.checkBody("pass", "Enter valid password address.").isAlphanumeric()
 req.checkBody("contact", "Enter valid address.").notEmpty().isNumeric()

    let error = req.validationErrors()
    if (error) {

        console.log(error)
       res.send("ok")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to simply move your `res.send("ok")` outside your `if` check for errors, because now it will send the response only if there are errors:

```
 app.post('/', (req, res) => {


let data = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    pass: req.body.pass,
    contact: req.body.ccontact
   }
  const action = req.body.action;
  if (action == "submit") {

 req.checkBody("name", "Enter a valid name  address.").notEmpty()
 req.checkBody("email", "Enter a valid email address.").isEmail()
 req.checkBody("pass", "Enter valid password address.").isAlphanumeric()
 req.checkBody("contact", "Enter valid address.").notEmpty().isNumeric()

    let error = req.validationErrors()
    if (error) {

        console.log(error)   
    }
 res.send("ok");
```

Comment: Dear thanks for your quick response, but i wana to send this res to other html file which is in my directory. from html file im send data via ajax.